# PHP - Create base64 encoded image from String

Tags: php, image, base64

I have array contain strings and I want to display them in image format (each image contain a string). I need display image in format: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,...<data>..."/>`, all images in a HTML page. How to create base64 encoded image from String?

I tried to search from google, but there are tutorials for "create base64 encoded image from image file".

Example: If my text is "600153957", the output will be:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

**Live example**: http://goo.gl/mYBUI . I want protect my numbers like this website. By this way, the spam software which scan text to find this numbers can't read them.

Please help me! Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: have you even tried doing it?

Comment: how does `600153957` become the base64 string you show in the example?? Not going to work like that

Comment: @RamRaider here is example http://goo.gl/mYBUI , all numbers is display in this format

Comment: is that number a telephone number? I don't see any examples on that page - just a long list of what appear to be names and addresses

Comment: Incidentally - it is still possible to read the contents of an image ( though it is complicated to do so ) - especially when it is basic text ( which is why Captchas tend to be so distorted )

Comment: @RamRaider Thank you for your answer! It really help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a rough example of how you could do what you want, you need to generate the image with php using whatever data you want and then get the file contents as a string

You'll get the idea if you run this code as it is.

```
<?php

    function b64img( $str, $fs=10, $w=250, $h=200, $b=array( 'r'=>255, 'g'=>255, 'b'=>255 ), $t=array('r'=>0, 'g'=>0, 'b'=>0) ){
        $tmp=tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), 'img' );

        $image = imagecreate( $w, $h );
        $bck = imagecolorallocate( $image, $b['r'], $b['g'], $b['b'] );
        $txt = imagecolorallocate( $image, $t['r'], $t['g'], $t['b'] );

        imagestring( $image, $fs, 0, 0, $str, $txt );
        imagepng( $image, $tmp );
        imagedestroy( $image );

        $data=base64_encode( file_get_contents( $tmp ) );
        @unlink( $tmp );
        return $data;
    }


    $img=b64img( 'Some text to make into base64 image', 6, 400, 100 );
    echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64, {$img}' />";

    $img=b64img( 'Another image', 10, 200, 200, array('r'=>0, 'g'=>255, 'b'=>0), array('r'=>255, 'g'=>0, 'b'=>0) );
    echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64, {$img}' />";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether below code helps you

```
$decodeString=base64_decode($imageString);
$imageCreated=imagecreatefromstring($decodeString);
ob_start();
imagepng($imageCreated);
$imgPng = ob_get_clean();
$imgPath = "data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($imgPng);
```

and $imgPath can be used as src for .

Comment: what is $imageString? How to create it? I want to generate image from text.

Comment: What will be that text, from which you want to create image. Is that an image stored somewhere?

Comment: sorry, it is not work.<code>    imagecreatefromstring(): Passed data is not in 'WBMP' format in...index.php</code>  imagecreatefromstring(): Couldn't create GD Image Stream out of Data  .  Many thanks for your help. I found answer from @RamRaider